# How to save Pdf file in SD card from Internet(url) in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to save Pdf file in SD card from Internet(url) in kotlin
Example if i have this pdf url :http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
how to save this pdf file in cd card

Comment: Just like any other file. Please explain your problems.

Comment: i will dawnlod it but can't open it on sc card

Comment: Show the code you have already.